# Bootstrap - change label position depending on screen width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form, I would like to position labels based on the screen size.

Currently I have this code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form name="addUser">

  <div class="row">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                     User Name <span class="required">*</span>
               </label>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.userName" class="form-control" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                     Password <span class="required">*</span>
               </label>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                     Email <span class="required">*</span>
               </label>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" class="form-control" />
    </div>


  </div>
</form>
```

This is the output :

[image]

I am trying to auto adjust this form on small screens like this :

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you read the documentation ? Just change to `col-xs-12` your labels and your input's parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `row` need to be used with **container** and as commented above, you have to change the value of `col-xs-`. For full width you need to specify **12** on the label so it takes all the width and push the input in the next row.

And you are not obliged to make the input `col-xs-12` you can use any lower value than 12 if you want them to remain small and not go full width:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form name="addUser">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    User Name <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.userName" class="form-control" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    Password <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    Email <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" class="form-control" />
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```